# Xamarin.Forms.Picker contents are duplicated in UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp, uwp-xaml, picker, xamarin.uwp

Xamarin.Forms.Picker controls duplicated the contents only when we touch the Picker using a finger. It is perfectly working with Mouse pointer.

So it created an endless scroll with duplicate items in it with touch.

If you have any Windows touch device you can experience this issue. I think this is a long-lasting issue but I could not find any solution for this.

Please suggest me if you have any idea on resolving the issue?

Comment: "this is a long-lasting issue" - is there already a bug report for it in the XF github?  If not, have you reported it?

Comment: @Jason I have noticed it few years back in Native ComboBox UWP but later I really had no purpose of using it. Now I can reproduce this issue in Picker control as well. There is no bug report for this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution for this problem by changing the ComboBox ItemPanel from CarouselControl to StackPanel. By default ComboBox uses CarouselControl which visualizes the loop behavior in touch mode. So by changing the template of the ComboBox ItemPanel to StackPanel resolved the issue for me.

Just put the following code in the App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```